# Use Tomcat Library in Webapp project

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, testng

I have a web application that uses the Tomcat library. I have not copied the jars from the Tomcat library into the web-inf/lib directory.

Now when I run an ant build / testNG class, it throws an error since the concerned jars are not present under the web-inf/lib directory.

Is there any way (configuration) that I can use the Tomcat library for the running the ant build  / testNG classes.

Thanks in advance,

Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`<testng>`](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html) task, just provide the tomcat libraries [as additional classpath elements](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path).

```
<TestNG>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
        <pathelement location="path/to/tomcat/lib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</TestNG>
```

Comment: @Vivek don't write this in a comment. Instead: either update your question or (better) ask a new question. and: thanks :-)

Comment: I have posted a new question as per your suggestion. Thanks :)