# Include Tomcat Library while running TestNG.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, testng

I am facing a problem regarding running the testng.xml.

I am using the Tomcat library in my project , and have not copied the jars into my WEB-INF\lib directory.

When I run testng.xml directly as it throws compilation errors , since the library being used is the Tomcat library.

Is there any way through which i can include the Tomcat library as a config param while running the testng.xml directly

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

Comment: How do you run the test? With ant? Note to others: this is a followup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109599/use-tomcat-library-in-webapp-project, **NOT** a dupe!

Comment: No , i run the test through Eclipse by right -clicking on the testng.xml and Run As --> TestNG Suite

I have installed the TestNG plugin in eclipse

Comment: OK, added the eclipse tag to the question. My Guess is that you would need to add the tomcat library to your eclipse project, but I don't know the details for that.

Comment: I have added the tomcat libray to the eclipse project , and since that is not present on the classpath of the project , the testng suite is unable to run in that case.
Hence would like to include the Tomcat lib in the classpath while running the testng.xml

Comment: @Sean
Figured out an alternative way to include the Tomcat Libray , added the library as a user library , and things worked out.

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sean
Figured out an alternative way to include the Tomcat Libray , added the library as a user library , and things worked out. Thanks for all the help :)

Thanks, Vivek